# How to get into a Master's program without funding?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, canada

Before you read the post, I would like to say that it is causing me a great deal of anxiety because there are so many obstacles that are put by the department and no one from the department is willing to hear me out. So I really need to speak to people who are already in the graduate school environment and perhaps dealt with similar issue.

I decided to apply to McGill university last month. I know the drill, I must email researchers about my interest in their lab etc , so I formulated a concise straight to the point email. Only one PI responded with a rejection. So when I contacted the graduate advisor about my issue ( No one is responding), she reached out to one of the researchers and the first thing he said " does the student have funding". She then told me that the department doesn't even consider an application the doesn't have funding. So I went to look for funding opportunities, and imagine my surprise when I found out that THE MAJORITY OF FUNDING opportunities are only open to registered students already in the program. So this is the Catch-22 paradox all over again.

I want to explain to the potential PI that it will be MUCH easier to secure funding once I'm a student because at this moment, no funding opportunities are available for me because I am not a student. The Graduate School Department at the school isnt helping, they keep referring me back to the department and the department is not responsive so I am here stuck unable to submit my application which is doomed to rejection without a chosen PI.

Comment: Err, I understand that you're frustrated, but what is the question you think strangers on the internet can answer about academia here?

Comment: I appreciate the need for you to give the relevant backstory, but I think the question basically boils down to "How to get admitted as a Master's student without funding?", or something like that. Perhaps you can refocus your question with this in mind?

Comment: I was hoping any suggestions on how I can assure prospective PIs that I'll apply for the grants once I'm a student. I did mention that in my emails that I will be applying to grant X and Y once I am a student, but this didn't seem to help.

Comment: @MadJack you mean do you want me to edit the title? I can do that :) Im sorry for my question not being as "well put together" as it should be, but I had just finished the round of calls to the department and the grad school unit and I was just fraustrated.

Comment: While that will sound harsh, what they most likely mean is that your candidacy is too weak for you to have a reasonable chance without your own external funding.

Comment: Apply for a scholarship and come to Germany. Education is free and there are scholarships by the state.

Comment: Emma, you can also edit your question after you have written it.  You can proofread it, make it concise, and while you're at it, lower the emotional tone.  It's understandable to be frustrated -- and a lot of people who post here looking for help are frustrated too.  But try to describe the situation you're in, and your feelings, in a neutral tone.  That will be good practice for the writing you will do in grad school.  Just click where it says "Edit" under the question.